# ImageView scale + translation animation

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale, translate-animation

I'm trying to achieve a quite complicated animation : I have got a shrinked image inside a ScrollView, and when I click on it, I'd like it to scale to its real X and Y + to end up being on the top of the ScollView and centered in the screen.

So, first question: is there a way to set a scale animation with a start and end with and height in dp?

And, second question: is there a way to set a translate animation with a start and end container view?

Answer (score 1):

Animations usually use pixel size parameters, but you can easily convert dp in pixel with a static method :

```
public static int dpToPixels(Context context, float dp) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

About you second question, I don't think that Animation can go cross its original view.

Comment: Indeed, it will not.
If your ImageView is a subview of the ScrollView, animating it to an origin point of (0,0) will put it to the top left of the ScrollView and not the whole screen. But he did say he wanted to animate it to the top of the ScrollView so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: On scale animation how can you set a start and end width and height. I have not found that on the documentation.

Comment: You can use constructor and pivot values :
 public ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue)

Comment: I know, but can you use width and height? I need to scale an image from a shrinken initial state to its original width and height.

Comment: fromX and toX params are scale value. So you need to set 0.0f for fromX and fromY, and 1.0f for toX and toY, and your animation scale will finish on original width an height